# How to recompiles .css files starting from bootswatch .less files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I succesfully installed node and less

I downloaded from bootswatch the following two files from them 'Flatly':

- [variable.less](http://bootswatch.com/flatly/variables.less)
- [bootswatch.less](http://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootswatch.less)

Now I'd like simply create the final boostrap.css without do any modification, just to try if all is indetical to precooked bootstrap.css files from the same theme.

I tried

```
lessc variables.less > bootstrap.css
```

But I got empty boostrap.css file

I tried

```
lessc bootswatch.less > bootstrap.css
```

But I got

> NameError: variable @navbar-default-bg is undefined in
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\ bootswatch.less on line 16, column 14: 15
>   background-color: #fff; 16       color: @navbar-default-bg; 17     }

So I tried this

```
lessc variables.css bootswatch.less > bootstrap.css
```

It give me no errors, but still I got an empty bootstrap.css file.

Is there any way to compile .css using directly less or absolutely must I do all of the steps listed at Customization [here](http://bootswatch.com/help/#customization) ?

Comment: You also need to download Bootstrap Less [sources](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.2.0.zip) and compile all this all together (for example by compiling a file like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/4ff8510d7be594f45ce5#file-25278043-less) (obviously using "flatly" files instead of "spacelab")).

Comment: Thanks this works, create a regular answer so I can approve it, but, please, copy/paste gist code, not simply link to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to get a Bootswatch customized Bootstrap css (if you don't want to bother with all that [black magic](http://bootswatch.com/help/#customization)) is the following:

1. Download Bootstrap Less [sources](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.2.0.zip)
2. Download corresponding Bootswatch `variable.less` and `bootswatch.less`.
3. Create new file with the following imports:

   ```
   // Set imported file paths to their actual location in your environment
   @import "..../bootstrap/less/bootstrap"; // <- Bootstrap  bootstrap.less 
   @import "..../.../bootswatch";           // <- Bootswatch bootswatch.less 
   @import "..../.../variables";            // <- Bootswatch variables.less
   ```
4. Compile this file with `lessc` (or whatever compatible tool).