# Keep getting SyntaxError "#gradient > .radial is undefined" when I compile my LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using a bootswatch theme called Paper, and I'm attempting to use Less for the first time  in a project. The problem is, every time I go to compile my Less code, I get a SyntaxError: #gradient > .radial is undefined on line 56, column 1

```
Line 56: #btn(default,@btn-default-bg);
```

That's the line it's catching on, and I can't seem to figure out why it wont't compile right. I'm not finding any syntax errors, and I've imported my variables.less file correctly as far as I know.

Am I doing something wrong? How do i fix this?

Comment: If you comment out that line, does the issue go away?

Comment: When I comment it out, it throws an error on the next line which is 
`#btn(primary,@btn-primary-bg);`

Comment: Can you include the Less code here, or at least the first 60 lines of it? Better yet, if you could throw it into a JSFiddle and link.

Comment: This is the exact Less file I'm using. https://jsfiddle.net/81ycyd0v/

Comment: The `.radial()` is a Less parametric mixin (http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), and it's probably defined in the `variables.less` file. Ensure that file is actually being imported. Check Chrome's developer panel and look for any errors (such as 404).

Comment: My import line is `@import "variables.less"; ` is that correct or no? it's at the top of the Bootswatch.less file.

Comment: I guess you don't have the correct path to the variables.less file...

Comment: Both files are in the same folder, I just have a folder called Less.

Comment: Bootstrap mixins are defined in "mixins.less". (Note that to compile proper Bootswatch theme you will need complete Bootstrap sources. Just `bootswatch.less` and `variables.less` of the Bootswatch itself are not enough).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recompiles .css files starting from bootswatch .less files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843927/how-to-recompiles-css-files-starting-from-bootswatch-less-files)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `@import` bootstrap.less first.

1. Add all `bootstrap/less` files to your solution
2. Add those `@import`s to your main.less file:

```css
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@import "paper/variables.less";
@import "paper/bootswatch.less";

/* My .less styling here */
```